# Java - Integers and Binaries

Tags: java, binary, syntax-error, decimal

Trying to create a program where you input binary numbers, and you get the sum of these two again in binary form. Why doesn't the code work;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
   class ABC{
      public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner toy = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = toy.nextInt();
        int y = toy.nextInt();
        x = 0bx; y=0by; ------------> ERROR SHOWS UP
        int z = x + y;
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(z));
        }
     }
```

The error message reads:

```
binary numbers must contain at least one binary digit 
';' expected
```

Ideal example:

```
x = 101 (integer) --> x = 5 (binary meaning of 101)
y = 10  (integer) --> y = 2 (binary meaning of 10)
z = x + y = 5 + 2 = 7
return binary form of 7 (111)
```

Comment: Typical programming languages don't let you be this creative with syntax, it would often be completely ambiguous anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote `0bx`, which were a nice programming trick if it worked. It doesn't, as you experienced yourself.

To see why, you need to know that the code you wrote is first interpreted as a whole, and is translated by the compiler into a program in machine code. In principle the compiler could figure out what you were trying to say with the `0bx` expression. It's just that the Java programming language doesn't allow this expression.

It says something similar to:

> A binary literal is written by `0b`, followed by only 0 and 1, at least one and as many as possible.

The word literal means something related to letters, "as written". Therefore you cannot use this part of the programming language.

But there's another part. The method `Integer.parseInt` has 2 variants: `Integer.parseInt("12345")` converts a decimal representation of the number into that number. The variant `Integer.parseInt("101110101101", 2)` parses a binary representation of a number into that number.

If there is a method `toy.nextInt(2)`, you can use that. Otherwise you have to use `Integer.parseInt(toy.next(), 2)`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your input numbers to be parsed a binary, you should read them as `String`s and parse to `int` in radix 2:

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(toy.next(),2);
int y = Integer.parseInt(toy.next(),2);    
int z = x + y;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(z));
```

As for your error:

```
x = 0bx; y=0by;
```

is not a valid syntax. The `0b` prefix allows you to enter numeric literals that would be treated as binary literals (for example `x = 0b1001;`), but you can't combine it with a variable.